# C# mvc web api. Convert json plain text to cipher text over http

Tags: c#, android, encryption, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am developing a mobile backend application which is written in c# mvc web api's.
I would like to know the best secure mechanism to transmit json data.
Is there any issue with sending data in json format, or should i convert that json to som encrypted format?
My actual data will look like this.

```
{
"id":2130,
"location":"florida"
}
```

my question is, is there any way to convert this json to some other format which can be decrypted at mobile side
say like as folllows

```
{
"zxs#%df":"dfd5d2f",
"fgfd5f5gdd":"fdgfdg699"
}
```

or as a plain text like

```
"dfsdfs^^dfsd^%$$fsdfsd*fs6556df$6"
```

which can be converted to actual json data

Answer (score 3):

Use HTTPS.

It is unlikely you can create our own protocol with comparable security.

Comment: can you explain in detail.If i use https then do i need to again encrypt json data?Or can i transmit it as such?

Comment: @user3079776 HTTPS is already encrypted. Just sending plain JSON is fine.

Comment: my question is can anyone hack and get the message even if i am using https?

Comment: @user3079776 yes, but resources required to perform an attack by person not directly involved into communication are generally outside of reach for most people (easiest option is to install custom trusted root on client's machine - on other hand it requires obtaining physical access/admin accesses to user's machine which open much more opportunities that just intercepting HTTPS traffic). Note that if you are trying to hid content from valid recipient of the message it is whole different story.

Comment: @alexei-levenkov-i would like to have a system  where my messages are 100% safe to transmit and no one can read event if they get the system.So what i understand is i must do https traffic.in addition to that some cryptographic method to encipher and decipher plain JSON text.Am i right??

Comment: @user3079776 when you find a way - there are plenty of people to pay for working approach. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use tokenization and pass tokens?

you can refere and check with  http://jwt.io/